# Jquery to find all divs with the same attribute value and add together their id values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've been searching for days for a way to do this and have tried amalgamating answers I have found on here but can't seem to nail this.

```
var found = {};


$("[user]").each(function(){
var total = 0;
var $this = $(this);
var rel = $this.attr("user");


if(found[rel]){
    total += parseInt($this.id, 10);

}else{
    found[rel] = true;
}

$(this).attr("id",total);
});
```

Basically I want to find all divs that share the same "user" attribute value and add their "id" values together.If anyone could lend a hand I would be very grateful!

Thanks!

Here is the code i'm manipulating:

```
<div class="stream">
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="3" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f3cfa7cd376"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show sample html and required result?

Comment: `found[rel]` will always be false, as you initialise `found` as an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

I understand from your question is, you want to find all the divs with same value and get the id of those value.

Use `map()` or `each()` with the `$('div[value="user"]')` as per your need.

```
var id = $('div[value="user"]').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get().join(',');
console.log(id);

var total=0;
$('div[value="user"]').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```js
var id = $('div[value="user"]').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get().join(',');
console.log(id);

var total=0;
$('div[value="user"]').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
});
console.log(total);


var total=0;
$('div.stream > div.listProfileHolder').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
});
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div value="user" id="10"></div>
<div value="user" id="20"></div>
<div value="user" id="30"></div>
<div id="user4"></div>

 
<div class="stream"> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="3" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f3cfa7cd376"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div> 
  <div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the question I think the OP literally meant add them together, not concatenate them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what is OP?

Comment: @Oluwafemi OP === Original Poster (@berniehm)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks! Learnt something new today :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! how would this work if user was an attribute, and it's the divs who's user attribute values match?

Comment: @BernieHm Just see the selector `$('div[value="user"]')`, you can replace / put your attribute as per your need. As value is an attribute in this.

Comment: @Loading.. thanks, darn - so there is no way to do this with the value being dynamic?

Comment: <div class="stream">
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="3" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f3cfa7cd376"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f28454a6d65"></div>
<div class="listProfileHolder" id="1" user="57f4bbc36f813"></div>
</div>

Comment: As I said, just make sure that you're using proper selector `$('div.stream > div.listProfileHolder')`, See I've updated my example and let me know if you find any problem?

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, only i'm not sure this is right still. I need to add together the div id values with matching user values, for instance in this case it would be the first div and the last div in the stream div added together to make 4, and like wise with all the other matching user ids?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should do it for you, or at least put you on the right path if your selector is like so: `<div class='user' id='78'></div>`

```
var totals = [];
var finalResult;
$(".user").map(function(o, b) {
  totals.push(parseInt(b.id))
  finalResult = totals.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, only i'm not sure this is right. I need to add together the div id values with matching user values, for instance in this case it would be the first div and the last div in the stream div added together to make 4, and like wise with all the other matching user ids? I've added more code above to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you are after:

```
var items = {};
$('div.listProfileHolder').each(function() {
  if (items[$(this).attr('user')]) {
    items[$(this).attr('user')] += parseInt($(this).attr('id'))
  } else {
    items[$(this).attr('user')] = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

https://jsbin.com/kahopadeca/edit?html,js,console